# Set 4 space Tab in Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, tabs, space

The tab button is moving 8 spaces but I would like for it to move 4 spaces.

Comment: Next time, try to put more text related with the question instead of a random text, like what you have tried, where you have search to find the option, what was your project, etc.

Answer (score 5):

To make Netbeans tab for 4 spaces: press "Tools" -> "Options" -> "Formatting". There should be a text field "Tab size" to set the tabbing size (see image bellow).

[image: Netbeans tab spacing]

Comment: I had to set it to "Number of Spaces per Indent" -> `4` and had to set "Tab Size" -> `16`

Answer (score 0):

For PHP users, in case "Tab size" number box is disabled, change "Language" to "All Languages" as shown above(Willmore's answer). Then the Tab size for PHP would become whatever you set there for "All Languages."